# multiple get requests in node js

Tags: node.js, http, get, httprequest

I'm working on a facebook chatbot. I have to make several GET requests according to users response. Right now I'm making all requests at once, since I don't know how to get the response out of the request function. Is there an easier way to it?

```
'use strict';
var https = require('https');

var options = {
    host: 'url.com',
    path: '/path_to_api'
};

var req = https.get(options, function(res) {

var bodyChunks = [];
res.on('data', function(chunk) {
  bodyChunks.push(chunk);
}).on('end', function() {
  var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
  body = ''+body;
  var json_body = JSON.parse(body);


  var options2 = {
    host: 'url2.com',
    path: '/path_to_api'
};

  var req = https.get(options2, function(res) {

    var bodyChunks = [];
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
       bodyChunks.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', function() {
      var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
      body = ''+body;
      var json_body2 = JSON.parse(body);
    })
 });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try create a bunch of requests with [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise):

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var requests = [
    rp(options), rp(options2), rp(options3) ...
];
Promise.all(requests).then(([restul1, result2, ...allOtherResuts]) => {
    //process ok
}).catch( err => {
   //handle error
})
```